# Sequence of program execution in Flex with PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, asynchronous, flex4.5

I am building a Flex and PHP application in which I am providing users a Save results option, which will invoke the php service that generates the results file. I then have the FileReference.download(url) function with the url of the file generated. Problem here is the popup to save comes before the file is even generated in the server. So user will get the incomplete file as the file generation will take atleast 10-15 seconds.

```
printToFile.token = customerTyped.printToFile(customerArray,displayno);
var filepath:String= "http://localhost/"+displayno+".txt";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(filepath); 
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference(); 
fileRef.download(request);**
```

I think the function(service) call to PHP function customerTyped.printToFile(customerArray,displayno);
does not wait for it to return and continues to execute the next statements  asynchronously.

How do i make the download dialog to wait from popping up until the printToFile  php function is completed.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a second PHP function to tell you whether the file is ready or not.

Another solution is to use a normal `URLRequest`, call your `printToFile` PHP function, then listen to the `COMPLETE` event - that should tell you when the file has been generated.